# TestRail: Remove documents from TestRun or TestResult

Tags: tools

In "[TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/)" tool (Manual Testing) I have attached two documents in TestRuns and Results while executing the Test case. Now I have to remove one document, how to remove the one document?

Answer (score 1):

In Test run, when You enter to test case, with attached document, in right column You can see this attachment. When You run with mouse pointer to this attachment, there will appear icon to delete. Bellow there are example of this:

[image: attachment]